# Android Kill all Open ProgressDialogs?

Tags: android, progressdialog

How would I ask the current activity for a list of any ProgressDialog's visible so that I can call their Hide() method?

Comment: Why would you have more than 1 progress dialog displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are all ProgressDialog objects that have been opened by your application, then you can keep a member (or even static member) reference to them when you create them.  Then, you can check the `isShowing()` method of each one to see if it is visible.

If you are looking for ProgressDialog objects from other applications, I do not think this is possible.